# Schengen Visa exipres a day before departure. Do I need to re-apply for visa?

Tags: visas, schengen, italy, visa-extensions

I applied for Schengen Type C tourist visa from 13th December to 24th December, 2014 in Italian Embassy, India. My flight from New Delhi will reach Rome on 13th of December and my return flight is on 24th December, 2014 afternoon from Rome. But on the visa which I received, it reads that it's valid from 13th Dec to 23rd December.

Now I am worried why the embassy gave me visa only till 23rd? What should I do now?

Comment: I think it would be much easier to change your ticket.

Comment: It looks like a clerical error; see if that's the case and if so, get an amendment to the visa.#

Comment: Thanks Jonathan and Gayot. I am weighing both the options. I have to wait till Monday to check with the Embassy.

Comment: Turns out its really hard to get a reponse for correction request from embassy. I have preponed my return flight. Thanks all for help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Coming from India, you can't stay in Schengen as a tourist without a visa. That means you won't be allowed to stay after the 23rd. http://www.schengenvisainfo.com/who-needs-schengen-visa/

To those who tell you that nothing will happen if you over stay, I can tell you about my personal experience the first time I left Schengen:

I overstayed because I thought I could stay 3 months instead of 90 days, and in those 3 months there were 91 days. I left on the day 91 and the border control noticed it immediately. They took me to a room for about 4 hours and made me endless questions: where have I been, what did I do, they asked me to prove all my stays and travels with tickets and receipts (which fortunately I had with me at that time), they made me sign a paper telling me that a process would start against me through my embassy for overstaying and that I might denied the access to Schengen in the future. Finally, obviously, I lost the flight I was supposed to take. So I had to pay for a new flight right there in order to leave Schengen. You can bet that with this sort of behaviour they make really sure that you will not over stay again.

Comment: This is really useful first-hand information. I am feeling lucky after hearing your experience that I decided to prepone my flight. I feel sorry that you had to face this. Thank you for sharing your experience.

Answer (score -2):

On your overstay of 1 day, you are not going to get deported. Whether this will affect future visas is difficult to know, especially as different countries, and different immigration officers may have different reactions. I would honestly not worry about it.

Edit: But note above, it may cause problems on exit in some places.

Comment: You could also get in trouble when landing. Border guards can and do ask about your plans and might check your ticket. Unless you lie (a bad idea in itself), they can therefore notice that you came intending to overstay and deny entry for that motive, even before you actually did it.